# OBS doesn't work on my raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, obs-studio

I'm a little french yotuber and I always use OBS in windows. Now, I use a raspberry pi 4 with debian bullseye and I tried to install OBS but it doesn't work. When I launch OBS from LXterminal, that say that:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ obs-exec
obs-exec: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have make some research but all of that doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Is there a *package* for `obs-exec` in `bullseye? If not, how did you install it?

Comment: Yes, there is a package for obs: `sudo apt-get install obs && sudo apt-get install obs-build` then, for launch obs there is two commands: `OBS` or `OBS-exec`

Comment: It must be new for `bullseye` - it doesn't appear in an `apt-cache` search on my `buster` version. RPi maintains a GitHub site, and a "discussion forum", so if you feel it's a bug, you could start there.

Comment: I already have make some research in internet and ask a question in the raspberry pi forum but I have no answers and no issues to my problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: I tried to run with root user and that says: `/usr/bin/obs-exec:error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I think that can help you to give me an answer for my problem

Comment: Apologies, but I don't know the answer. I do see the packages in `apt-cache` now, and there are 6 separate packages for the Open Build System. Perhaps the missing library is in one of the packages you did not install?? You can list these packages in your terminal with the following command: `apt-cache search obs | awk /^obs-/`

Comment: I tried this command, so I missed the package obs-plugins. I have make the comman but that doesn't work :( `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install obs-plugins
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 1267 (packagekitd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Impossible d'obtenir le verrou de dpkg (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend). Il est possible qu'un autre processus l'utilise.`

Comment: With pi-apps, I have found an other screen recorder but I prefer OBS. Please help me to find an issue !

Comment: Per your request, I have posted a very generic answer. Again, I am not a user of OBS, so this is all I can offer. You may also wish to consider posting on [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit OS?

Comment: No but I have box86, an emulator for run 64 bits and x86 apps normally

Comment: Did you try this using the `buster` release of `bullseye` - #1 in my answer?

Comment: I don't have a mass storage to install `buster` :(

Answer (score 0):

Per your request, and based on your comments, you may wish to consider the following:

1. `bullseye` is a recently released distro from *"the Raspberries"*. The RPi OS (née *Raspbian*) is a *Debian derivative*, and generally is not released for several months after the Debian release. In my experience, I have encountered various issues adopting newer releases, and so I have adopted a policy of waiting 6 months - 1 year after the release date before upgrading. All of this is to say that you may want to "start over", by installing `buster` on your system.

   But before doing that, let's try to get OBS installed on your `bullseye` system:
2. I don't know how your system is configured, or what steps you may have taken in the process of installing OBS. On the *hunch* that there is a system conflict, the following might help:

   - Remove the existing OBS installation:

     ```
     sudo apt-get purge XXXX
     ```

     `XXXX` are any and all of the OBS programs you installed.
     *Please note that `purge` removes all configuration files, so consider saving those if you may need the information later.*
   - `update` & `upgrade` your system to get the latest kernel & libraries ***before*** you install a new package(s):

     ```
     sudo apt update 
     ...
     sudo apt upgrade
     ...
     sudo reboot  
     ...
     sudo apt-get install XXXX
     ```

And that's it for me... I'm not an OBS user, so these are all very generic suggestions. Bon chance!

Comment: Thanks Seamus. You're nice! I'll try it and I say you if it works

Comment: That looks better work but I have a new error ;(

Comment: @In_The_Nether: ***Maybe*** the problem is related to `bullseye`??? ... If it were my system, I would try installing on `buster`. This will be easier if you have an extra SD card. You should also try the [forum for Linux users of OBS](https://obsproject.com/forum/list/linux-support.34/). This may be a "known" issue - perhaps there's a solution?

Comment: @In_The_Nether: [This search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=OBS+on+raspberry+pi&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web) may have some useful resources.